# Applet no initialized

Tags: java, applet

I am writing this code and trying to run it using appletviewer .

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.applet.*;

public class FirstApplet extends Applet
{

/* <applet code="FirstApplet" height=200 width=300>
</applet> */

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
    g.drawString("First Applet program ",50,30);
    }
}
```

I'm compiling it by javac FirstApplet.java
and running it with appletviewer by writing Appletviewer FirstApplet.java

But, the problem is that I'm not getting the expected output . 
Indeed it's just showing that the applet is not initialized .

Can anyone help me out with the above? What should I do to make it run properly? I'm running Windows 7, on a dual core processor with 3GB of ram. 
The version of java is jdk1.7.0_45.

Comment: have u called it from html

Answer (score 0):

Appletviewer requires a that the class be loaded from a HTML file containing an applet tag

```
<applet code="FirstApplet" height=400 width=300></applet>
```

Some side notes:

- It's considered good practice to declare classes in packages.
- `java.applet.Applet` is incredibly old. Take a look at Swing's `JApplet`

Comment: Ya bro I'm even giving the HTML code but still it's not getting loaded i.e, not being initialized . I want to know about java.applet.Applet as it is a part of my University process . Anyone please help me out .

Comment: Are you running it with `appletviewer htmlfile.html`? Is the class file in the same location as the HTML file?

Comment: I'm running it in command prompt using Appletviewer FirstApplet.java

Comment: Check out the usage [docs for appletviewer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/appletviewer.html) - the syntax is `appletviewer htmlfile.html` (!) :)

Comment: The thing I'm unable to understand is that in my college the applet is running perfectly but not at my laptop .